# swift nsoutlineview open always one root element

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

I work with swift 3 and Xcode 8 for macOS.
I use an nsoutlineview (without TreeController and in ViewBased Mode)

i would like to realize, that always one root element with their child element(s) can be open. if i open another one, the actual open root element should close and the new one will open.

for that i have  try it with the following code:

```
@IBAction func outlineViewClickedRow(_ sender: NSOutlineView) {

for x in (0..<outlineView.numberOfRows) {               
outlineViewn.collapseItem(outlineView.item(atRow: x), collapseChildren: true)
}
outlineView.expandItem(outlineView.item(atRow: outlineView.selectedRow))

}
```

this IBAction is assign to my outlineView.
basically it works good.

but the problem is:

- if I click on a root element, which is actual open, my function will open it again. this looks not professional...
- and this "Click" Function will work also for elements, which are not expandable - this is not so good, too

i tried this code to solve the first point:

```
if (outlineView.isItemExpanded(outlineView.selectedRow) == true) {
  print("isExpanded")
}
```

but the print result will never shown.
itItemExpanded is always false ...

same problem for second point:

```
if (outlineView.isExpandable(outlineView.selectedRow) == true) {
  print("isExpandable")
}
```

is Expandable always "false"

Comment: nobody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your loop collapses all items, once it is done, the selectedRow item will always be collapsed at the end of the loop.  This will inevitably close and reopen the selected item if it happens to already be expanded.  (BTW you can collapse all nodes by passing a nil item to that function instead of using a loop)

If you check outlineView.isItemExpanded(outlineView.selectedRow) at the start of the function an just exit if it is already expanded, that should solve your first issue.

For the second point, you have to set the "isExpandable" property of the items somewhere (which you either did not do or did not show us).

I don't know which event your outlineViewClickedRow function is linked to but you have to make sure that outlineView.selectedItem contains what you expect.  Depending on which event it is, the row selection states may not get updated before outlineViewClickedRow is called (which could cause some inconsistant results).

One more thing, did you somehow disable or hide the native expansion icons (triangles) from your outline view ? If not, the user will be able to expand multiple top nodes without  going through your automatic collapsing logic.

[EDIT] I had time to test the event behaviour and the outline's selection seems to be updated before the call to the IBAction.  The following function should perform the automatic expansion and collapsing correctly:

```
@IBAction func outlineClicked(_ sender: Any) 
{
  autoExpandAndCollapse()
}

func autoExpandAndCollapse()
{
   guard let selectedItem = outline.item(atRow:outline.selectedRow),
             outline.parent(forItem: selectedItem) == nil
   else  { return }  

   for level1Index in (0..<outline.numberOfChildren(ofItem: nil)).reversed()
   {
      if let topLevelItem = outline.child(level1Index, ofItem: nil),
         outline.isExpandable(topLevelItem)
      {
         if outline.selectedRow == outline.row(forItem: topLevelItem)
         && !outline.isItemExpanded(topLevelItem)
         { outline.expandItem(topLevelItem)   }
         else 
         { outline.collapseItem(topLevelItem) }
      }
   }
}
```

BTW, I assumed that you only wanted this to apply to the top level nodes.  If not, you can probably adjust the logic to your requirements.

[EDIT2] adjusted to fix bug that closed parent when child with same sibling index was clicked, simplified code a bit.

Comment: hey Alain T. thanks for your answer. can you show me your explanation as a code example ? that is better for me to learn :)

Comment: now i use outlineView.collapseItem(nil) instead of the loop to collapse all items. thanks for this tip. i only link my outline view like this `@IBAction func outlineViewClicked(_ sender: NSOutlineView) { }`as click event.

Comment: if I only put this code in to my function `print(outlineView.isItemExpanded(outlineView.selectedRow))` it always print "False" if i expand an item

Comment: It is likely that the OutlineView's item expansion is only performed after the outlineViewClicked() event is called so at that point the item is not yet expanded.

Comment: yeah, it is very close, but there have to be a litte bug. some child elements collapse the root element on click. an idea? :)

Comment: Yea, that was my bad. I used the child index as if it was a row number.  I updated the code.